# SCNNode Plane not being correctly detected after rotation

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scnnode

I have an horizontal plane being detected. Once it's detected, I want that plane, which is a rectangle, to always appears horizontal (width > height).
this is the code I'm using to create this SCNNode:

```
  func createFloorNode(anchor: ARPlaneAnchor) ->SCNNode {
    let geometry = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(anchor.extent.x), height: CGFloat(anchor.extent.z))
    let floorNode = SCNNode(geometry: geometry)
    floorNode.position = SCNVector3(anchor.center.x, 0, anchor.center.z)
    floorNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red 
    floorNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
    floorNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(-Double.pi/2, 0, 0)
    if geometry.width < geometry.height {
      floorNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(-Double.pi/2, -Double.pi/2, 0)
    }
    floorNode.name = floorNodeName
    return floorNode
  }
```

After this, I have a tapped gesture funtion added, which I want it to let me know if I have tapped inside my SCNNode:

```
  @objc func tapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let sceneView = sender.view as? ARSCNView else { return }
    let tapLocation = sender.location(in: sceneView)

    let hitTest = sceneView.hitTest(tapLocation, types: .existingPlaneUsingExtent)
    guard !hitTest.isEmpty else {
      print("Not a plane")
      return
    }
    print("Touched on the plane")
  }
```

Problem is, after I rotated my scnnode, that functions keeps detecting the plane as the old one (before being detected). If I don't rotate it, it works fine.

Any ideas?